# How to make custom functions available in all PHP scripts?

Tags: php

i have some functions like below.I am using this functions alot.Is there anyway to use this functions in my scripts on the fly like default predefined php functions ?...

```
function get($URL){ 
        global $cookie;
        $ch = curl_init ($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://domain.com/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL);
        $page = curl_exec ($ch);
        return $page;
    }
```

For example i need to use custom functions like below.

```
<?php
echo get("http://domain.com");
?>
```

note : i dont want to use `include 'config.php'` aswel..just make it work like default functions.

Comment: I suggest you to use a php framework if you are not using one already, and create a Library with all of your functions. P.E. with laravel you could do easily what you want without the use of includes.

Comment: No. Core functions are actually mostly C code and unless you're willing to write a PHP Extension in C, I don't see this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why don't you simply include the file? That's how you are supposed to do it.**

Another option would be including the file automatically using [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) (via php.ini or `php_value` in .htaccess if you are using mod_php). You still need the file but you won't have to write an explicit `include` or `require` statement.

However, I point at the first statement again. Using `auto_prepend_file` only helps you being lazy. It will make the code less readable and IDEs won't know about the function you are trying to use and will highlight it as undefined - because for any tool that doesn't know about the `auto_prepend_file` that function *is* undefined.

Comment: thanks i just want to explore this kinda things ..

Answer (score 4):

Configure it as [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and it will be automatically included in any php script.